Dimming/Darkening another Win32 Window
Is there a way to 'dim' another window, that does not belong to your process? Not reducing opacity (that's easy to do using SetLayeredWindowAttributes), but make the window more dark.

No, this is not supported.

Maybe UpdateLayeredWindow might be what I'm looking for? I'll to create a working solution with it, some examples of it render a image from a file.

UpdateLayeredWindow() requires you to provide a bitmap for the entire window.  You can't do that of you don't own the window. In this case, I would simply create a solid black translucent window and place it on top of the target window

Placing a translucent window on top of another window inhibits the latter from receiving mouse input.

UpdateLayeredWindow doesn't seem like what I want to do. Seems like there is a way to allow click through. So now I would need a way to synchronize the positions and state(minimized/maximized) of the target window with my overlay window. I think the easy way would monitoring it every ~1s and updating the overlay (so there will be a 1s lag), but is there a more performant option?

You could try to use WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message
